# Inheritance and base constructor

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

So I'm trying to teach myself to program and I'm making a rpg battle thing for practice. (basically just a very simple old rpg battle system in c#) However, I'm a little confused on inheritance. So I have a base class Enemy:

```
class Enemy
{
    public string name;
    public int health;
    public int attack;
    public int level;

    public Enemy(string _name, int _health, int _attack, int _level)
    {
        name = _name;
        health = _health;
        attack = _attack;
        level = _level;
    }
}
```

And then I have this class `Dragon`:

```
class Dragon : Enemy
{

}
```

Why is it saying that

> there is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal
>   parameter '_name' of 'Enemy.Enemy(string, int , int, int)?

My thought was that it would use the enemy constructor, Do I have to make each derived class its own constructor?

Comment: Yes you will have to create a constructor in classes that derive from `Enemy` because constructors are not inherited, and those constructors will have to call your `Enemy` constructor.

Comment: If `Enemy` had a parameterless constructor, that would be called automagically when the subclass is constructed, but it doesn't have one. If (and only if) `Enemy` didn't define any constructor, the compiler would provide it with a parameterless constructor automagically. This makes sense: You can blow off the whole constructor thing for free, but if you get involved in it, the compiler gives you total control.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The basic answer to your question is **yes**. Your derived classes must define a constructor, specifically they must do so when no default constructor is available on the base class.

This is because base class constructors are always fired when derived classes are created (in fact, they are fired *first*). If you don't have a constructor to pass the base class constructor its required arguments, the compiler doesn't know how to handle this.

In your case, something like

```
public Dragon(string _name, int _health, int _attack, int _level)
  :base(_name, _health, _attack, _level)
{
}
```

Will get you started. You may need (and can have) other parameters for your `Dragon` of course. You can also pass literals into the base constructor (so you don't need to parameterize the `Dragon` one with all base class arguments).

```
public Dragon(string _name)
  :base(_name, 1000, 500, 10)
{
}
```

The only requirement is that an existing base class constructor is used.

Comment: Just to expand on this great answer: The subclass constructor doesn't need to have the same arguments as the base-class, it can have more, or less, or even none at all.  As long as the `base` statement supplies the arguments that the base class expects, it will be happy.

Comment: OOOO okay that clears it up for me a lot, thanks ! Just to make sure, essentially what ': base' is saying is use the info from base correct?

Comment: @Yummy275 No; it is saying "use the base class constructor that matches the arguments that follow"

Comment: It is essentially a call to the base class constructor.  You could think about that line actually being the very first line in the subclass constructor body. The only reason it has that special syntax is that it enforces the call to the base class, as it is absolutely required.

Comment: @Yummy275 Without `: base` the compiler attempts to use the base's default constructor, which doesn't exist for your base class

Answer (score 3):

Since the base class has a constructor and it always fired when derived classes are created then you should either add a parameter-less constructor to the base class:

```
class Enemy
{
    public string name;
    public int health;
    public int attack;
    public int level;

    public Enemy(string _name, int _health, int _attack, int _level)
    {
        name = _name;
        health = _health;
        attack = _attack;
        level = _level;
    }

    protected Enemy()
    {

    }
}
```

Or implement the constructor in the derived class like this:

```
public Dragon(string _name, int _health, int _attack, int _level) 
 : base(_name, _health, _attack, _level)
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have to declare a constructor in `Dragon`. You could declare a parameterless constructor that calls the base constructor:

```
public Dragon() : base("test", 1, 1, 1){}
```

or implement an own parameterized constructor.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if i completly understand your question.
You want to create a Instance of your class Dragon and using the constructor of the Enemy-Class?

In this case you need to add a own constructor to the Dragon-Class and there you add the 'base' keyword to forward your parameter from the Dragon-Constructor to the constructor of the base-class. Like this:

```
class Dragon : Enemy 
{
    public Dragon(string _name, int _health, int _attack, int _level) : base (_name, _health, _attack, _level)
    {

    }
}
```

You can even add some additional parameter to the constructor of you 'dragon'-Class which you don't have to forward into the base-Constructor like:

```
class Dragon : Enemy 
{
    public string DragonStuff { get; private set } 

    public Dragon(string _name, int _health, int _attack, int _level, string _dragonStuff) : base (_name, _health, _attack, _level)
    {
         DragonStuff = _dragonStuff;
    }
}
```